# VOIP notification with CallKit is not invoking reportIncomingCall when app is inactive killed state

Tags: ios, notifications, voip, callkit, pushkit

It's a video calling app. I have implemented VoIP notifications to receive a video call. On receiving VoIP notification, I am using CallKit to call `reportNewIncomingCall()`.

When I minimise the app, I receive the incoming call and the flow works fine.
But when I kill the app, I am not getting the incoming call. Any idea why?
I also noticed that when I tap and open the app next time, it gets crashed :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push callback.'
```

This says that I am not posting `reportNewIncomingCall`. But I am already doing it and getting call when app is minimized.

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry,
                  didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload,
                  for type: PKPushType,
                  completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
     
    }
    completion()
}
```

Only on killed state, I don't get the calls. What else to be done to receive calls in killed state? Please help.

Comment: For me, I found that having fetch background mode enabled prevented receipt of PushKit notifications. Go figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to call the `pushRegistry` completion handler inside the `reportNewIncomingCall` completion handler?

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry,
                  didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload,
                  for type: PKPushType,
                  completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
        completion() // <----
    }
}
```

Even if it's not clear in the documentation, I think it's the correct way to handle a new incoming call.

Comment: @BrianChristo did this work for you? I am seeing the same behavior